# Jetpack Compose nested navigation and BottomAppBar

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to use jetpack compose navigation, but I had a problem in understanding nested navigation and layout the scaffold.

I had an app screen structure like this

```
root
├─ A
├─ B <- Had a bottom navigation bar
│  ├─ C
│  ├─ D
```

and this is the rough specs

- The root would be in the MainActivity and have a NavHost and scaffold.
- The app bar in A and B would be different.
- There would be a bottom nav bar in B, which can be used to navigate between C and D

I have been looking through the docs and StackOverflow, from what I get it is best to just put the scaffold outside of NavHost.

But, for my case how can I update the app bar in A and B it if I don't get an access to the scaffold inside A & B? I can only think to make a branching in the scaffold like the code below

```
Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    topBar = {
        when {
            currentDestination?.parent?.route == "Home" -> {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = {
                        Text("Home")
                    },
                )
            }
            currentDestination?.route == "Other screen" -> {
                 ....
            }
```

Also I need an access scaffold state in A.

So what is the best approach to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: I have the same question and another issue with the nested navigation. I have similiar structure and because Route B has a own bottom navigation bar and thus an own NavHost, how can I navigate from Screen C (opened from the tab bar) to Route A? See also here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71423059/jetpack-compose-nested-navigation-with-bottom-bar-navigation-in-a-nested-route

Comment: I did some search again and found out some people are using multiple NavHost. See https://github.com/arefhosseini/compose-multi-navigation . However, I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: @Andra is correct, using multiple navhosts is not the recommended approach. That being said I am having a hard time coming up with a solution that has a scaffold/bottombar at an inner level using only one navhost

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with `NavHost` and nested navigation with multi `Scaffold`.

**Here is my first solution:**

The root has its own `NavHost` that contains 2 separate pages(A & B) and these pages have its own functionality.

If we consider page A is kind of single page like Splash Screen, we have a basic `Scaffold` component to it.

And if we consider page B is kind of multi pages with bottom navigation like Instagram, at the top level we should create a `NavHost` for that own page.

Here is our root:

```kotlin
sealed class RouteScreen(val route: String) {
    object A : RouteScreen("a")
    object B : RouteScreen("b")
}

@Composable
internal fun RootNavigation(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    appState: MultiNavigationAppState
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = appState.navController,
        startDestination = RouteScreen.A.route,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        addA(appState)
        addB(appState)
    }
}

private fun NavGraphBuilder.addA(
    appState: MultiNavigationAppState
) {
    composable(route = RouteScreen.A.route) {
        AScreen()
    }
}

private fun NavGraphBuilder.addB(
    appState: MultiNavigationAppState
) {
    composable(route = RouteScreen.B.route) {
        BScreen(appState)
    }
}
```

`AScreen` is a composable that you can use `Scaffold` in it.

`BScreen` is same as `AScreen` but you can create another `NavHost` for control tabs.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun BScreen(
    appState: MultiNavigationAppState
) {
    val mainState = rememberMainState()
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {...}
    ) {
        BNavigation(...)
    }
}
```

Actually it's not recommended to use one `NavHost` with nested navigation because if pages have tabs and its functions like Instagram, we get in trouble.

Second solution is that we can use multi `fragment` with own `NavHost, but it's not all based on` Composable` components.

As you mentioned I face this issue and you can get more help with [this Github project](https://github.com/arefhosseini/compose-multi-navigation)

Comment: This uses 2 NavHosts.